# Delete a table, name create with ??vml_template in mysql

Tags: mysql

Mistakenly I have created the table with junk like ??users

How can I delete that table?

Table name - ??vml_template

```
mysql (test) > show tables;
```

```
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_test       |
+----------------------+
| ??vml_template       | 
+----------------------+
```

```
mysql (test) > truncate table ??vml_template;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??vml_template' at line 1

Comment: Use ` around table name.

Comment: mysql (test) > truncate table `??vml_template`;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.??vml_template' doesn't exist

Comment: `'test'.'??vml_template'`  (but with ` instead of ')